# Running Selenium Tests on different browsers using pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'v got UI tests (pytest) and a Selenium grid. And I want to run my suit on differnt browsers at the same time. For example:

```
py.test test.py --browser "internet explorer;chrome"
```

I expect two parallel sessions on different hosts in my Selenium grid.

test.py:

```
class TestSuit:
    def test_1(self, app):
        app.do_smth()
        assert True

    def test_2(self, app):
        app.do_smth()
        assert True
```

application.py:

```
class Application:
    def __init__(self, browser_name):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://host:port/wd/hub,
            desired_capabilities={'browserName': browser_name}
        )
```

conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize(
        'browser_name',
        metafunc.config.getoption('browser').split(';'),
        scope='session'
    )

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app(browser_name):
    return Application(browser_name)
```

But i get running my tests on the first host with IE and right after on the second with Chrome.

How to run two parallel sessions on each host simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You can try threading instead, as the above code will not allow parallel execution.

```
 import threading

def worker(num):
    """your required work"""
    print  num
    return

threads = []
for i in range(2):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```